# Display 'N/ui/message' bar when viewing records

Tags: suitescript2.0

Is it possible yet to display the custom message bar when viewing a record, or only during edit (pageInit)?

Client script is OK for EDIT, but CSS don't fire in view mode, and UES before load doesnt work either.

```
    /**
     * @NApiVersion 2.x
     * @NScriptType ClientScript
     * @NModuleScope SameAccount
     */

    define(['N/ui/message'],
    /**
     * @param {message} message
     */

    function(message) {

        function showMessage() {
        console.log('exec pageInit');
        message.create({
            title: "Message Title",
            message: "Message Text",
            type: message.Type.INFORMATION
            }).show();
    }

    return {
        pageInit: showMessage
    };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible yet to display the custom message bar when viewing a record

Yes it is possible.

In **view mode**, `pageInit` of **client script** is not triggered, so you can either use worflows, or modify your logic to be trigerred from **userevent** to show message using `N/ui/message` module.